# List references - memory // PYTHON

Tags: python, list

New here, and I start learn python by myself. I saw this picture. Can anyone please explain to me what happens to the list when "a" changed? Does it still stays in the memory or ethernaly deleted?

[image]

Sorry for my bad English (not my native language)
Thanks again!

Comment: Need to edit the question, the picture is not uploaded correctly...

Comment: Don't use pictures or links. Include all relevant code in your question *as text*. See [mcve].

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here, but thanks for the notes... for the next times I'll do my best

Comment: If you have background in C, consider variable names as pointers. The information you have asked about is lost

Comment: @Chris_Rands - so if i understand right, it delets the former list?

Comment: @freude - no sorry. my first time studying to code...